# Powerset of infinite set minus original set equivalent to the poweset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had this idea which I am fairly certain is true but I am not quite certain nor how to go about proving it. Let $\alpha$ be a given infinite set of some cardinality, that is $card(\alpha)=a$ and let $set(\alpha)$ be the set of all singleton sets of $\alpha$. That is if $z\in set(\alpha)$ then $z=\{q\}$ for some $q\in\alpha$

Now my idea is about the cardinality of the difference between the powerset of $\alpha$ and the singleton sets, my idea is that
$$|\mathcal{P}(\alpha)-set(\alpha)|=|\mathcal{P}(\alpha)|$$
I may be wrong but it feels intuitive and I am not quite certain how to go about it.

I know all I need is a bijection between the two given set but I am not certain how to construct it in a rigorous manner that would pass the traditional necessities. I do know on the other hand that $|set(\alpha)|=|\alpha|$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\alpha)|>|\alpha|$ which is what leads me to believe it must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that for infinite cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$, the following holds: $\kappa+\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$. And note that $\mathcal P(\alpha)=(\mathcal P(\alpha)-\mathrm{set}(\alpha))\cup\mathrm{set}(\alpha)$ is a disjoint union.

(You may wonder, why do we have to use the axiom of choice, in the form of $\kappa+\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$. The answer is that it is consistent that there is a counterexample, where $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ is an infinite Dedekind-finite set, therefore removing elements decreases the cardinality. It suffices, for this proof, however, that for every infinite cardinal $\mathfrak m$, $\frak m+m=m$.)

Comment: Well it is true but I feel it is not a good enough proof really, I'd prefer some bijection

Comment: Well. Unless you appeal to the axiom of choice directly, you can't quite "write down a bijection". Even in Brian's hint you don't *really* end up writing a bijection. So it's unfortunate that you prefer that, it's not just not going to happen... :-)

Comment: Axiom of choice do you get stuck with either or no matter what, they are real bastards :P I was mostly aiming at the structure of the idea, I get idea of your proof though, it has a charm in it's simplicity but there is somethign about it that makes me feel it is not rigorous enough. Just a feeling of mine

Comment: The thing about cardinal arithmetic is that you prove its correctness by producing "bijection schemata". Namely, if you pick specific functions at the specific parts of the proofs, you will get an actual bijection. Just unwind the cardinal arithmetic that I've suggested using, and you'll be one happy camper, albeit exhausted from all the details. Or, to quote many people, explicit bijections are overrated.

Comment: You got a point at the end, it has been a nagging issue as I grew in mathematics that one tends to stay on firmer grounds of explicit functions and such while in mathematics it only suffices to prove it must exist therefore we're all happy.

Comment: Well. Infinite sets are rarely ever explicit. Which is why the axiom of choice plays a large role in taming them.

Comment: Someone should write a book called "Taming of the infinity" :P

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Clearly $|\wp(\alpha)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\alpha)|\le|\wp(\alpha)|$, so you just need an injection from $\wp(\alpha)$ to $\wp(\alpha)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\alpha)$. One approach is to let $p$ be any object not in $\alpha$, and let $\beta=\alpha\cup\{p\}$.

- Show that $|\alpha|=|\beta|$ and hence that $|\wp(\alpha)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\alpha)|=|\wp(\beta)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\beta)|$.
- Now consider the map from $\wp(\alpha)$ to $\wp(\beta)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\beta)$ that takes $\varnothing$ to itself and takes every non-empty $S\subseteq\alpha$ to $S\cup\{p\}$.

Comment: Do you mean p is an object not in $set(\alpha)$? Because if we're technical the powerset has only sets in it and all those sets contain elements of $\alpha$

Comment: @Zelos: No, I meant what I wrote. I’m not adding $p$ to $\wp(\alpha)$: I’m adding it to $\alpha$. The point is that there is a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and it gives rise to a bijection between $\wp(\alpha)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\alpha)$ and $\wp(\beta)\setminus\operatorname{set}(\beta)$ that can be used to good effect.